# Python how to go back to main menu

Tags: python

This is my code I want it to go back to the main menu after I press a button

```
numberoftries = 3
while numberoftries > 0:
    print("You have 3 tries")
    username =(input("Enter the username"))
    password = (input("Enter the password"))
    if (password) == "password" and (username) == "MrLee123":
        import time
        time.sleep(1)

        print("Username and password accepted")
        print("Choose a student")
        print("1.) Hanif Adolecense")
        print("2.) Kerlo Sumpage")
        print("3.) Kearien Honter")
        print("4.) Mex Whitermen")
        print("5.) Tolu Ohyeahbola")
        print("Press enter to quit")
        answer = input("Select an option")
        numberoftries = 0
        if answer == "1":
                print("Hanif Adolescense")
                print("ID Number:12376")
                print("Surname: Adolescense")
                print("Forename: Hanif")
                print("DOB: 24 Dec 2001")
                print("Address: Somewhere in Nigeria")
                print("Number: ")
                print("Gender: Male")
                print("Tutor group: G")
                print("School email: 13h.adolecense@dallam.com")
```

how do I make go from an answer like 1 back to the menu

Comment: Where are you decrementing numberoftries ?

Comment: You can use swtich case in something like this

Comment: @zenwraight In Python?

Comment: I meant something like switch logic, make the code more modular by splitting it into different methods

Answer (score 0):

Add at the `if` level:

```
else:
    number_of_tries -= 1
```

This will break wile loop after 3 unsuccessful atteempts. Then call anything that moves user to main meanu after the `while` loop.

Comment: _"Then call anything that moves user to main menu"_ Call what? That's exactly what the OP doesn't know how to do.

Comment: As far as I understood, the problem was with implementing logic that breaks the loop. If it's not the case, OP should provide broder example, since I do not even know what the `main menu` is. Anyway, summon @Karlo43210 could you clarify this?

EDIT: I'll delete this answer if I misunderstood your intentions.

Comment: He should provide his whole code to us, then only we can understand